# Spring Security with AJAX authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-security

I am trying to use *Spring security* to authenticate a web application to protected resources using AJAX, as in, a popup dialog rather than the default redirect to a separate login form. However I am having real trouble getting my noggin around this problem. I have tried to implement a test based on the contents of the following URL:

http://www.cavalr.com/blog/Spring_MVC_-_Spring_Security_with_AJAX_and_JSON

But to no avail - the dialog remains open and the controller is not called.

I have read conflicting information that says the AJAX URL must `POST` to `j_spring_security_check` and that it will expect the login and password form components to be named according to Spring security's requirements.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: **the dialog remains open and the controller is not called** show some code and let us know which spring and security version you use?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security Web was designed during the time when JSP was the primary UI code. Therefore the default implementation of success/failed authentication is to redirect user to a success/failed page. If you are building Web 2.0 based application which is heavily using Ajax, you'll need to extend spring security code to always return json/XML to your UI code.